# Tree Distortion in Shiny Modal

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-modal

An instance of collapsibleTreeSummary() becomes distorted as it's rendered more than once in the same modelDialog() within a Shiny app. The tree is compressed after the modal and tree are rendered more than once, making it difficult to comprehend.

For example, this code displays a horizontal tree, representing an artificial company's headcount by division.

***Modified***

```
library(shiny)
library(collapsibleTree)

choice1_data = data.frame(
  V1 = c(rep("Corporate",3),"Sales"),
  V2 = c("Finance","Marketing","HR","Sales"),
  V3 = c(110,43,12,243)
)
choice2_data = data.frame(
  V1 = c(rep("Corporate",3),"Sales","IT"),
  V2 = c("Finance","Marketing","HR","Sales","IT"),
  V3 = c(110,43,12,243,22)
)
choice3_data = data.frame(
  V1 = c(rep("Corporate",3),"Sales","IT","Management"),
  V2 = c("Finance","Marketing","HR","Sales","IT","Management"),
  V3 = c(110,43,12,243,34,22)
)
ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    br(),
    actionButton("mainButton","Click me"),
    br(),
    uiOutput("jobcodeRadio")
  )

)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  output$jobcodeRadio = renderUI({

    div(
      style="display:flex;align-items:top;",

      div(
        class="jobcodeRadioStyle",
        div(
          radioButtons(
            "JOBCODE",
            "Explore a Role of Interest:",
            choiceNames=c("choice 1","choice 2","choice 3"),
            choiceValues=c("choice_1","choice_2","choice_3")
          )
        )
      )

    )

  })

  output$tree = renderCollapsibleTree({
    selected_choice=input$JOBCODE
    if(selected_choice=="choice_1")
    {
      df=choice1_data
    }
    else if(selected_choice=="choice_2"){
      df=choice2_data
    }
    else{
      df=choice3_data
    }
    collapsibleTreeSummary(
      df,
      root="Fake Corporation",
      hierarchy=c("V1","V2"),
      zoomable=T,
      attribute="V3",
      nodeSize="V3",
      tooltip=T,
      linkLength=250,
      fontSize=12
    )

  })

  plotModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      title = NULL,
      size="l",
      easyClose=T,
      # Display the tree
      fluidPage(collapsibleTreeOutput("tree"))

    )
  }

  observeEvent(input$mainButton,{
    showModal(plotModal())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

1st time being rendered
[image]

Subsequent times being rendered

[image]

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved when I render data tree in shiny `renderUI({})` function instead of in `fluidPage()` :

```
 plotModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      title = NULL,
      size="l",
      easyClose=T,
      # Display the tree
      renderUI(collapsibleTreeOutput("tree"))

    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens, but the proper way of displaying UI (apart from text) inside a `modalDialog()` would be to create a function to trigger the modalUI as mentioned [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html).

So I just moved your `collapsibleTreeOutput` and `renderCollapsibleTree` outside the button's observe event and included the `plotModal()` inside the button's observe event.
This function will generate the proper UI.

Here's the modified code

```
library(shiny)
library(collapsibleTree)

df = data.frame(
  V1 = c(rep("Corporate",3),"Sales"),
  V2 = c("Finance","Marketing","HR","Sales"),
  V3 = c(110,43,12,243)
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    br(),
    actionButton("mainButton","Click me")
  )

)

server <- function(input,output,session){

  output$tree = renderCollapsibleTree({

    collapsibleTreeSummary(
      df,
      root="Fake Corporation",
      hierarchy=c("V1","V2"),
      zoomable=T,
      attribute="V3",
      nodeSize="V3",
      tooltip=T,
      linkLength=250,
      fontSize=12
    )

  })

  plotModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      title = NULL,
      size="l",
      easyClose=T,
      # Display the tree
      fluidPage(collapsibleTreeOutput("tree"))

    )
  }

  observeEvent(input$mainButton,{
    showModal(plotModal())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helpes!
P.S I'm still not sure why the UI is rendered from the top when clicked >1 times

Comment: Thank you for response. But still the issue exists when I have added three radio buttons and modifying the  tree data by choosing the one of them.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example by editing your question?